# Is it guaranteed that fingerprint data taken by a scanner can be reused by another scanner?

Tags: optics, image-sensor

I want to create a system that records employee attendance with optical finger scanner. Because the scanner has a limited lifetime, replacement with the same kind in the future might be impossible due to some reasons such as discontinued products, collapsed factories, etc.

## Questions

Is it guaranteed that fingerprint data taken by a scanner can be reused by another scanner?

Comment: You can pretty much be sure that at some time in the future, perhaps not very far in the future, you will have difficulty with any stored data required to make any electronic device work. That is probably a corollary of Murphy's Law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. It depends on the finger reader output. PIV/FIPS compliance or FBI IQS compliant interfaces are compatible, Raw image storage sensors **are not.** guaranteed.

Yes only if the output is compatible. But at the system level the data is extracted as fiducial or minutia data extracted that is compatible with applicable standards.  These are the 5 basic features look for 5 fingerprint types (loop, arch, whorl, radial loop, double loop). within the print and their R, theta scaled positions.  Then there are unique patterns, permanent scars but not cuts surface burns.

Then the software must have an algorithm with a defined False positive and true negative acceptable error rate for matching or a limited database with more relaxed matching.

read here for a list of compatible scanners
http://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?group=platforms_linux_mac

Comment: Are there any finger scanners that can produce raw finger print images such that I can implement my own algorithm to maintain compatibility?

Comment: yes the ones without smarts and PIC certs may be your best start in my link in either linear scan or array scan. Then choose / modify the right SDK for compatability. Again you MUST start with a spec for False Positives, True Negative and True Positive or Probab. of certainty. Which demands a sub-spec or design choice for resolution, SNR and number of pattern true match and false match with tolerances, (fiducials coordinates and types) Added security can use different wavelengths for reflective detection as fingers also are semi-transparent to IR but not UV or blue or use thermal scan sensing.

Comment: Then consider sensitivity to product evolution on your design and tolerance to SNR, resolution and contrast ratio and always have a second source. Retina scanners are 100x better except bifocals or frames across the iris will cause loss of detection.  ( your photo resembles a keg more )

Comment: Which sensor technology (capacitive, thermal, hybrid, optical, etc)  is better against tempering?

Comment: The ones that can't be faked with a latex printed fingerprint image over one's finger.  (none that I've seen, but there may be some)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it guaranteed that fingerprint data taken by a scanner can be reused by another scanner?

No.

(I'd really love to write a longer answer, but there's simply not much to it – such systems are proprietary, depend on the properties of the actual sensor, the algorithms used to process the sensor data, the algorithms used to compare fingerprints, and the manufacturer knowledge of how to talk to the system components. So: No.)

Comment: Is it possible just to use  finger scanners to capture finger prints and produce raw finger print images? If it is possible, let our own application algorithm make comparison against a database of raw finger print images.

Comment: my answer pretty much states exactly that: It's up to every finger print sensor manufacturer to define which data the sensor gives. So, again, no general statement can be made.